# Acessar pagina de outro navigation usando nested navigation

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation

Estou tentando acessar uma pagina, no react-native, que está em outra rota e está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

**"The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload '{"name":"Routes,"params":{"type":"Navigation/NAVIGATE","routeName":"FinanceiroCliente"}} was not handled by any navigator. If you are trying to navigate to a screen, check if the screen exists in your navigator. If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see...."**

Segui as orientações da documentação de react navigation para nested routers e não funcionou.

link da documentação: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Meu código:

arquivo de rotas -

```
function Telas() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Atualizar"
        screenOptions={{gestureEnabled: true}}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Principal" component={Principal} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Pedido" component={Pedido} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Produtos" component={Produtos} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Clientes" component={Clientes} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Faturas Abertas" component={FaturasAbertas} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Atualizar" component={Sincronizacao} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

function Routes() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Principal"
          component={Telas}
          options={{headerLeft: null}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="FinanceiroCliente" component={FinanceiroCliente} />
      </Stack.Navigator>    
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Chamada da pagina:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Routes',NavigationActions.navigate({routeName : 'FinanceiroCliente'}))
```

Tenho dois navigators, um drawer e um stack, e preciso acessar uma pagina que está no stack a partir de uma tela que está na estrutura do meu drawer mas dai ocorre o erro.
O que estou fazendo errado? Dai busquei bastante coisa na internet e não consegui resolver o problema.
Grato desde já a quem pudem ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando dois `NavigationContainer`, ao invés de apenas um, isso faz com que não consiga navegar entre eles(ao ativar a função `independent`).

Você não precisa de dois `NavigationContainer`, remova o que está no `Drawer` e vai funcionar normalmente.

Da uma olhada na doc do react navigation, ele tem um exemplo de nested navigators: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Sobre o `independent` no `NavigationContainer`:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/packages/core/src/BaseNavigationContainer.tsx#L111

Comment: Funcionou aqui! Obrigado pela ajuda!